# Is there any website where we can view live orbit of all satellites to scale?

Tags: artificial-satellite, orbit, analysis

As the question says,
Is there any website or app which has a graphical view of all satellites which are currently in orbit with sizes to scale. An option to view in fast forward is appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

I do not know of any that includes a forward/rewind function, but there are several that show current positions very accurately.

A very friendly one is [Stuff in Space](https://github.com/jeyoder/StuffInSpace), hosted on different locations such as https://sky.rogue.space and https://ajmas.github.io/ThingsInSpace/

This displays a zoomable, 3d rotateable view of Earth space, showing all the tracked objects.
It can highlight a chosen object or group of objects, and has a search function for the selection.

[image]
This example shows Navstar 26, a GPS satellite.

Comment: Thanks, any ideas where i can view satellites in the entire solar system?

Comment: @Ashvin try https://eyes.nasa.gov/apps/orrery/#/home

Comment: @BrendanLuke15 Thanks